# How do I merge two lists?

Tags: python, arrays

Is there an existing function for merging two arrays like the following?
Eg.:

```
arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
arr2 = [1, 2, 3]

arr3 = merge(arr1, arr2)
print(arr3)
```

Output: `[["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]`

Comment: In Python those are called "lists" not arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `zip`:

```
>>> arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> arr2 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [t for t in zip(arr1, arr2)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

If you want each pair to be a list instead of a tuple:

```
>>> [list(t) for t in zip(arr1, arr2)]
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
```

or:

```
>>> list(map(list, zip(arr1, arr2)))
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
```

Comment: First one is just `list(zip(arr1, arr2))` :)

Answer (score 0):

As the OP was asking for a list of lists instead of a list of tuples , posting the answer here for completeness.

Altough no inbuild function can generate list of lists but the below will get what you need

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[5,6,7]
list(map(list, zip(a, b)))
```

Output

```
[[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7]]
```

Comment: Samwise beat me by few minites :)